# Find a basis for a subspace (working included)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, vector-spaces

I have been working on this question and I am not too sure if it is correct or not. Any help would be appreciated.

Question (in picture format): https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFteb.png

My working:

The first thing we should recognize is that we have 1 more variable than equation. That guarantees that we will have at least 1 degree of freedom so our solution cannot be just 1 point.

1 -1 1 0

2 -3 1 0

---

1 -1 1 0

1 -2 0 0

---

0 1 1 0

1 -2 0 0

So the reduced equations are:
z = -y

x = 2y

It is now clear that we have a degree of freedom and thus, when we solve for all the variables, they will be in terms of another.

z = -y

x = 2y

y = y

So the solution is: <2, 1, -1>y (after factoring out y) and the basis of the solution set is <2, 1, -1>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly right.${}{}$